# Valid ConcurrentDictionary usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I got a piece of code where an `Entity` can make multiple operations, one of those operations for example is rate an `Entry`. But I want to limit concurrency with lock free code, so the Entity cant send the rate operation to the same entry at the same time. So in my mind got two options:

- Create a new object where I have the Entity, the associated Entry and a field so I can use `Interlocked.CompareExchange`. (This means I would need to store this object in a concurrent list, search for it if its present, and then check for the field)
- Use `ConcurrentDictionary`, create a unique key for the Entity rating in the Entry and use `TryAdd` method. So if it returns false it means that its already making the operation. (I like this idea a lot).

An example of how I would use `TryAdd` to check if the entity is already rating an entry:

```
class OperationBlocker
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<String, Entity> ops
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<String, Entity>();
    
    private String contextID { get; } //Ignore this

    public bool StartOperation(Entity entity)
    {
        return ops.TryAdd(entity.id.ToString() + contextID, entity);
    }
        
    public bool EndOperation(Entity entity)
    {
        return ops.TryRemove(entity.id.ToString() + contextID, out entity);
    }
}
```

What you guys think of using `ConcurrentDictionary` and specially `TryAdd` for this?

Comment: If `OperationBlocker` a singleton?

Comment: Not at all, i will instance this class in many other classes i use.

Comment: Looks fine for me for this use case. You don't need to have Entity as value in dictionary by the way, can use dummy `byte` (always 0) instead.

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary will work. I don't quite understand what you mean by "limit concurrency with lock free code" because ConcurrentDictionay uses locks.

Comment: Well, "fine grained locking".

Comment: You don't limit concurrency with lock-free code. You can perhaps limit *contention* with lock-free code.

Comment: You probably can just use a concurrency token, and generically apply it to all of your entities